# Convert this in Perl curl -v -H "AUTH_USER:$user" "$url" 1> "$tmpfile" 2> "$hdrfile"

Tags: perl, shell, curl, libcurl, filehandle

I am trying to convert this shell command into perl I am using use WWW::Curl::Easy;

I want to write the verbose in a different file and i want to get the URL content into a different file . Till now i have been able to curl the URL and add header to it as well .

Now I want to just write the as shell command mentions output from 1> into a file and

2> into antohter file as it is there in shell

```
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();
        $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1); 
        $curl->pushopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['AUTH_USER:John']);
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL,"www.abc.com");
        $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
```

how do i put the content of www.abc.com that is

```
<html>
<body>
<marquee>abc is up </marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

into one file

And this into another file

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: abc-01
Accept: */*
AUTH_USER:hojn

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
......
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursory reading of the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm#WWW%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aEasy) and [libcurl docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEHEADER) reveals that you probably need:

```
    # A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
    my $response_body;
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

    my $response_header;
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER,\$response_header);
```

Comment: so the where do we define file handle ? , suppose we have to write to a file in /usr/bin/header.txt /usr/bin/content.txt , where do you define that ?

Comment: You define that and write to it just as you would for any file.

Comment: the response_body contains the response header as well , I just want to html code into one file and the verbose in another , but her the response body contains the full response that is getting , I just want to write the html code of the URL i am curling into a file

Answer (score 0):

When using libcurl, it's useful to have its [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) handy.

Browsing through the options, we find [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` & `WRITEHEADER`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHEADERFUNCTION) and [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` & `WRITEDATA`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Curl::Easy qw( /^CURLOPT_/ );

my $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

my $easy = Net::Curl::Easy->new();

open(my $fh_header, '>:raw', 'header.out') or die $!;
open(my $fh_data,   '>:raw', 'data.out'  ) or die $!;

$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,         $url);
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $fh_header);
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,   $fh_data);
$easy->perform();
```

---

Note: I used Net::Curl over WWW::Curl because I know and trust it. The above should also work with WWW::Curl as long as it provides a Perl-aware default for `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`. It it doesn't, you'll need to provide values for those options too.

Comment: in the data.out file the header is also getting written for some reason I just want to html code inside data.out .any way to do that

Comment: header.out is coming perfectly , but the data.out is containing the data that is there in header.out as well